# For a single text input use a text reader for parts and a binary reader for other parts

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I'm trying to parse a mixed text and binary stream by alternately reading it via [BitSyntax](https://github.com/theburningmonk/BitSyntax) and [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx). It works well enough except that both the bitsyntax and streamreader readers buffer ahead, so I've had to resort to code like

```
let pos = stream.Position
let title = read_c_string stream_reader
stream.Position <- pos + int64(String.length title + 1)
```

Can anyone think of a more elegant way to do this? One idea I had was to add null-terminated-string support to BitSyntax, passing in an Encoding as an argument, so that I could deal with a single reader. But it feels like I should be able to compose two different stream readers cleanly without having to modify the source of either. Another idea (which I'm leaning strongly towards at the moment) is just to slurp the entire stream into a byte array, and then do non-streamy things like splitting on `'\000'` for the text portion, and wrapping MemoryStream objects around slices of it to pass to BitSyntax. But ideally I would like to just use the Stream APIs and let one stream reader start reading precisely where the other one left off without having to manually fiddle with the stream position.

Comment: [`System.IO.BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1) looks to do everything that BitSyntax does, plus length-prefixed strings. If it's null terminated, you can `ReadChar` repeatedly and stop on '\0'. (`ReadChar` is smart enough to deal with character encodings.)

Comment: thanks, completely missed that BinaryReader could do encodings. if you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin [`System.IO.BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1) does everything that BitSyntax does, and can handle character data respecting the selected character encoding through it's `GetChar` method.

The only thing to watch out for with this is that `ReadString` is for length prefixed strings. For null terminated strings, you'll still need to read them character by character.